# If you moved your hand continuously through fire, would it feel hot?

Tags: everyday-life, convection, heat-conduction

If you quickly pass your finger or hand through a candle or fire, it doesn't feel very hot (great party trick). Is this because your hand spends such little time in the fire that there isn't enough time for conduction to occur? Or, does the motion of your hand prevent the heat-transfer process from beginning (to a significant degree)? If you continuously moved your hand through fire, would it feel hot?

Comment: Several different cooking techniques involve continually moving meat through, or above a heat source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is this because your hand spends such little time in the fire that
> there isn't enough time for conduction to occur?

Pain occurs when the skin temperature reaches the threshold of pain. The temperature of the skin due to exposure to the candle flame is the result of the combination of the skin's heat absorption rate and the duration of exposure of the skin to the flame. For example, one study showed that the theoretical threshold of pain and blister for a one second radiant heat exposure on thin skin to be about 2.5 watts/cm$^2$ and 5 watts/cm$^2$, respectively.

According to a Wikipedia article, the heat release rate of a candle flame is about 80 watts. So clearly the heat is sufficient to cause pain as well as a burn. Therefore, if pain does not occur it's simply because the exposure time was too brief for the skin temperature to reach the threshold of pain.

That said, it is foolish to perform such experiments due to the risk of burn injury.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Instead of performing such experiments, I ask the stack exchange :)

Comment: @aRockStr Just to be clear, when I said it would be foolish, I wasn't referring to you. The statement was addressed to the general (Stack Exchange) public.

Comment: You can do it with a thermometer instead by mounting it on a wheel part of which goes through the fire. Or...you know...a delicous steak.

Answer (score 3):

I am answering because I can't comment Bob D (my reputation is below 50)
As Bob D said for burn to occur the minimum intensity is 2.5 to 5 watt/cm² (in SI units 25000 to 50000 watt/m²)

So reason one is that skin exposure time to 80W candle is less than 0.125 to 0.0625 seconds (125 to 62.5 milliseconds)

And second reason is that when you move your finger in flame, the flame blows by the wind created by fast moving finger [you can try this by moving your finger fast in front of your palm, you'll feel the wind or by moving your finger fast above the flame, you'll see that the flame is getting blown by the wind created by your finger (ie flame will be hit by air molecules that got kinetic energy from your finger)] so most of the time the flame gets blown from the finger (not fully, it remains at the bottom (wick) but not near and around the finger) and your finger or hand remains untouched to the flame.
Second reason occurs when your finger is fast enough to create a light wind

Comment: "And second reason is that when you move your finger in flame, the flame blows by the wind created by fast moving finger ". My experience suggests that this is not a major factor in reducing the heat transfer rate. I'm not saying you are wrong . Just that  in my experience it doesn't seem a major factor.

Comment: @BobD when you move your finger fast enough very light wind is felt by flame (that's enough for blowing flame temporarily/around finger)                  but when you move it not fast enough then enough wind is not created to sway the flame.        So it depends upon speed of finger or hand

Answer (score 0):

What happens depends on a balance of the numbers:

1. How fast you move your hand through the fire
2. How often you move your hand through the fire
3. The proportion of time your hand spends away from the fire before
   moving back through it
4. How far away your hand is away from the fire when out of it
5. Plus all the normal stuff like how how the fire is.

If your there is a net transfer of heat into your hand and the temperature at which the heat transfer equilibriates is higher than which will burn you, then your hand is going to get burned. If not, then it doesn't.

More of 3 and 4 gives your hand more opportunity to shed the heat absorbed from the fire.

More of 1 provides a cooling breeze when your hand is sufficiently away from the fire (if your hand is too close to the fire it will still absorb heat from the fire). More of 1 also reduces the time that your hand spends over the fire limiting how much heat can be absorbed.

More of 2 gives your hand more total time to absorb heat but also gives your hand more time to cool so it's effect depends on how the other factors interact.